# check if a ViewController is being opened by TabBar's Tab or by a segue

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift2, uistoryboardsegue

okay so my app's hierarchy is something like :

`TabBarController` --> `SeprateNavigationControllerForEveryChildVC` --> `5ViewControllers` , 
so from my `VC1(ViewController)`  am opening `VC2` which is working fine but am also opening `VC1` from `VC2` , so now i want to check if my `VC2` is being opened by `VC1` or not so that i can make some changes in my `VC2`

i tried this in my `VC2` `viewDidAppear`

```
    if self.isBeingPresented() {
        // being presented
    print("isBeingPresented")
         }
    else if self.isMovingToParentViewController() {
        // being pushed
         print("being pushed") }
```

but its not printing anything , 
and this is how am performing the segue from `VC1` to `VC2`

```
if segue.identifier == "selectChannelSegue"{

        let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let viewController2 =  navigationController.childViewControllers[0] as! SelectChannelsTableViewController
        viewController2.delegate = self

    }
```

any idea how am gonna do that ?? if yes then do guide me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func isModal() -> Bool {
        if (presentingViewController != nil) {
            return true
        }
        if presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == self {
            return true
        }
        if navigationController?.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == navigationController {
            return true
        }
        if (tabBarController?.presentingViewController is UITabBarController) {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
```